# Copy all elements with atleast 1 child element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to copy all node elements from source XML that have **at least 1 child element**. Such nodes can be present at any hierarchy level. I want to perform this using **XSLT**.

My Input:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <node1/>
        <node2/>
        <node3/>
        <node4>
            <node5/>
            <node6/>
        </node4>
        <node7>
            <node8/>
            <node9>
                <node10/>
            </node9>
        </node7>
    </node>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
    <node/>
    <node4/>
    <node7/>
    <node9/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this 2 ways, either by straight template matching, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- this template copies all the nodes --> 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- this is an override template to delete nodes without children -->
    <xsl:template match="*[count(*) = 0]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

alternatively, you could loop through the descendants with children and output their names, as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[count(*)&gt;0]">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```